# Location access permission alert not showing and CLLocation manager delegate method not calling in xcode 6.4 . Please advise

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have done CLLocationmager in Objective C class. Here , My code is,

```
CLLocationManager *loc = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
[loc setDelegate:self];
[loc requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[loc requestAlwaysAuthorization];
loc.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
loc.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
[loc startUpdatingLocation];
[loc startUpdatingHeading];
```

Then added privacy settings in .plist file.
Still the am not getting any response in that.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager?language=objc

> 3. Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class and store a strong reference to it somewhere in your app.
>
>    Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete. Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient.